# From C++ MD2 Loader to C\Objective-C & Cocoa

Tags: c++, c, file-io

This afternoon I decided to make a simple 3D Game on Cocoa & OpenGL based on what I've done on one of my OpenGL class.  I'm using the MD2 loading code that is posted at David Henry's ["The Quake II's MD2 file format"](http://tfc.duke.free.fr/old/models/md2.htm) and I like how it's put together, giving nice explanations, and nice C++ code.

I want this to go all Cocoa/Objective-C so I can get the feel for the stuff and I got to a part which I cannot translate to C - I simply do not got enough experience in programming.

Here is the code in question, which relates to file reading:

```
// read frame data...
file.seekg( header.ofs_frames, std::ios::beg );
file.read( (char *)buffer, num_frames * header.framesize );
```

So, my question is this: is there an equivalent for seek() on C's file functions that I can use? Any related info you think I might find useful?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`fseek`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fseek.html) and [`fread`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html) from `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for resources for how to do this, but I found a great tutorial at the Kode80 blog: http://kode80.com/2009/09/24/iphone-md2-example/

There is a sample project in which the author wrote an MD2 reader for Objective-C/OpenGL ES from the MD2 spec (http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/md2-specs-en.html)